# Nested loop not working, only inner loop loops

Tags: python, loops, file-io, input, nested

I'm trying to display a raw gray image (8bit/pixel) i captured from my webcam with python.

The code i am using in python for displayinh the captured image is:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import cv

mat = cv.CreateMat(640, 480, cv.CV_8UC1)

#Open image
pipe_in = open("gray.raw","r")
#Fill matrix with raw gray values
for y in xrange(640):
    for x in xrange(480):
            graypixel = pipe_in.read(1)
            mat[x,y] =graypixel
            print graypixel

print "Hello"
```

I get the following output:

```
A
@
... 480 values
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./displaygray.py", line 9, in <module>
    for x in xrange(480):
TypeError: a float is required
```

It's like only the inner loop loops once and then it quits. I don't really get what i'm doing wrong.

Comment: Your code works just fine; your traceback however points to a line that doesn't match the exception. Try restarting your interpreter and/or cleaning up stale bytecode files.

Comment: And how do you restart your in a proper way? I only have gray.raw as a bytecode file

Comment: I strongly suspect that the `displaygray.py` source code is out of sync with what Python is running. To confirm, make an obvious error in that file. If you cannot make that obvious error show, you are running stale code.